# neo4j plugin for Gephi does not import - just blank error message

Tags: neo4j, gephi

installed Neo4j plugin 2.1.3; Gephi 0.8.2

Java 1.7, Windows 10

I've seen lots of posts for 2014 where users are having the same blank error pop-up when trying to import.

Are there any configuration details i can look at to see what the problem is.  Already altered the JDK home to point to Java 1.7

Comment: You need to have an old neo4j version. The plugin works for me for neo4j 2.0.3

Comment: anybody else have any suggestions where i don't have to roll back my version of neo4j ?  thanks

Comment: See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767482/neo4j-export-to-gephi. Basically you can export to GraphML and from there it is easy to import to Gephi

Comment: **UPDATE**: Tried the GraphML export with Gephi and seems to be running quite well...