# Neo4j export to Gephi

Tags: neo4j, gephi

How would I export the data in my neo4j database for use in the gephi program? You can export it as json or csv in the dashboard but that doesnt work in gephi. I am using using neoclient right now to manage cypher queries but it seems like they do not have methods to do this.

Comment: I have a blog post in progress that allows you to stream data from Neo to gephi: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14493611/blog/adoc/gephi_streaming.adoc

Comment: You can use APOC to stream as Michael says.  https://tbgraph.wordpress.com/2017/04/01/neo4j-to-gephi/  Works well.

Comment: @Doug, this doesn't allow asynchronous export/import. Is there any solution to perform 2-steps export/import in Gephi ? Through JSON export for example ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Neo4j-Gephi plugin](https://github.com/gephi/gephi-plugins/tree/neo4j-plugin), but I don't believe it supports the most recent versions of Neo4j.

The best method is probably to use export functionality in [neo4j-shell-tools](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools#export) to export to CSV or GraphML.

Comment: I tried recently and it doesn't. The plugin says it supports version 2.1.3 but I installed 2.0.4 and then got it work. Always GraphML is a good idea ;)